# Are upstream activating factor (UAF) and upstream binding factor (UBF) the same thing?

Tags: terminology, transcription, ribosome, transcription-factor, rrna

During ribosome pre-40S and pre-60S synthesis, many sources state the importance of UAF or UBF in initiation complex of ribosome DNA transcription. None of the sources I've seen mentions the other when mentioning UAF or UBF, so I want to know if they are actually the same thing.

Another source of confusion is that Wikipedia has article for both:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstream_activating_factor

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBTF

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many sources: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7982918, http://jcs.biologists.org/content/126/21/4815.long

Comment: Another source: http://biochemical-pathways.com/#/map/2
If you look at nucleolus part of chart, there's only UBF mentioned.